# BeEF does not start in Parrot Security OS

Tags: apache-httpd, parrotsec

I'm having problems, I wanted to follow tutorials on the [beEF](http://beefproject.com) (Browser Exploitation Framework) tool, but it just does not run. When I start it by the terminal, it should show the control panel in the browser but instead it shows me this:

```
Unable to connect

Firefox can not establish a connection to the server at 127.0.0.1:3000.
```

The apache server is normally running at 127.0.0.1.

The output of the terminal is as follows:

```
┌─[root@parrot]─[~]
└──╼ #beef-xss
[*] Please wait as BeEF services are started.
[*] You might need to refresh your browser once it opens.
[*] UI URL: http://127.0.0.1:3000/ui/panel
[*] Hook: <script src="http://<IP>:3000/hook.js"></script>
[*] Example: <script src="http://127.0.0.1:3000/hook.js"></script>
1479086364875   addons.productaddons    ERROR   Request failed certificate checks: [Exception... "SSL is required and URI scheme is not https."  nsresult: "0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/CertUtils.jsm :: checkCert :: line 145"  data: no]
1479086544345   addons.productaddons    ERROR   Request failed certificate checks: [Exception... "SSL is required and URI scheme is not https."  nsresult: "0x8000ffff (NS_ERROR_UNEXPECTED)"  location: "JS frame :: resource://gre/modules/CertUtils.jsm :: checkCert :: line 145"  data: no]
1479086545880   addons.update-checker   WARN    Update manifest for {972ce4c6-7e08-4474-a285-3208198ce6fd} did not contain an updates property
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The BeEF installed on [parrotsec](https://www.parrotsec.org/) is currently broken. It fails to start a webserver, probably due to missing files.

Install BeEF from [source](https://github.com/beefproject/beef) and follow the INSTALL.txt carefully.